# How to handle side effects based on multiple events in a message driven microservice system?

Tags: events, apache-kafka, state, event-sourcing

we are currently working in a message driven Microservice environment and some of our messages/events are event sourced (using Apache Kafka). Now we are struggling with implementing more complex business requirements, were we have to take multiple events into account to create new events and side effects.

In the current situation we are working with devices that can produce errors and we already process them and have a single topic which contains ERROR_OCCURRED and ERROR_RESOLVED events (so they are in order). We also make sure, that all messages regarding a specific device always go onto the same partition. And both messages share an ID that identifies that specific error incident. We already have a projection that consumes those events and provides an API for our customers, s.t. they can see all occurred errors and their current state.

Now we have to deal with the following requirement:

### Reporting Errors

We need a push system that reports errors of devices to our external partners, but only after 15 minutes and if they have not been resolved in that timeframe. Our first approach was to consume all ERROR_RESOLVED events, store the IDs and have another consumer that is handling the ERROR_OCCURRED events in a delayed fashion (e.g. by only consuming the next ERROR_OCCURRED event on the topic if its timestamp is at least 15 minutes old). We would then be able to know if that particular error has already been resolved and does not need to be reported (since they share a common ID with the corresponding ERROR_RESOLVED event). Otherwise we send an HTTP request to our external partner and create an ERROR_REPORTED event on a new topic. **Is there any better approach for delayed and conditional message processing?**

We also have to take the following special use cases into account:

- Service restarts: currently we are planning to keep the list of resolved errors in memory, so if a service restarts, that list has to be created from scratch. We could just replay the ERROR_RESOLVED messages, but that may take some time and in that time no ERROR_OCCURRED events should be processed because that may result in reporting errors that have been resolved in less then 15 minutes, but we are just not aware of it. **Are there any good practices regarding replay vs. "normal" processing?**
- Scaling: we may increase or decrease the number of instances of our service at any time, so the partition assignment may change during runtime. That should not be a problem if we create a consumer group for each service instance when consuming the ERROR_RESOLVED events, s.t. every instance knows all resolved errors while still only handling the ERROR_OCCURRED events of its assigned partitions (in another consumer group which is shared by all instances). **Is there a better approach for handling partition reassignment and internal state?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

For side effects, I would record all "side" actions in the event store. In your particular example, when it is time to send a notification, I would call SEND_NOTIFICATION command that emit NOTIFICATION_SENT event. These events would be processed by some worker process that does actual HTTP request.

Actually I would elaborate this even furter, since notifications could fail, so I would have, say, two events NOTIFICATION_REQUIRED, and NORIFICATION_SENT, so we can retry failed notifications.

And finally your logic would be "if error was not resolved in 15 minutes and notification was not sent - send a notification (or just discard if it missed its timeframe)"